# Using threading.timer to delay sub-procedure

Tags: python-3.x, pyqt4, self

```
def emailCheck(self):
n=0
(retcode, messages) = mail.search(None, '(UNSEEN)')
if retcode == 'OK':

    for num in messages[0].split() :
        n=n+1
        typ, data = mail.fetch(num,'(RFC822)')
        for response_part in data:
            if isinstance(response_part, tuple):
                original = email.message_from_bytes(response_part[1])

                print (original['From'])
                print (original['Subject'])
                typ, data = mail.store(num,'+FLAGS','\\Seen')
print (n)

t = threading.Timer(10.0, emailCheck)
t.start()
```

I am trying to delay the sub-procedure using threading.timer(), but I think the error is to do with the inclusion of self in the brackets. I am using PyQt so all of this is contained within the class MainWindow.

The error:

```
Exception in thread Thread-1:
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Python33\lib\threading.py", line 637, in _bootstrap_inner
self.run()
File "C:\Python33\lib\threading.py", line 823, in run
self.function(*self.args, **self.kwargs)
TypeError: emailCheck() missing 1 required positional argument: 'self'
```

Comment: `t = threading.Timer(10.0, self.emailCheck)`

Comment: If ekhumoro's answer doesn't solve the problem, can you please add slightly more code that shows where the`emailCheck` function/method exists (if it in a class?) and where the timer instantiations happens with respect to the function/method. As it stands, your current indenting makes it difficult to determine the relationship between the bits of code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

t = threading.Timer(10.0, self.emailCheck)